# Why does a constraint for the UIViewController.UIView to child UIViewLabel throw error "Invalid pairing of layout attributes"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to position a label so that the top of the label is 2/3 the way down the UIViewController.  So I wrote this constraint, but it gives me the error below.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *labelTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myLabel
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                            toItem:self.view
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                        multiplier:0.66
                                          constant:0];
```

The Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: 
Invalid pairing of layout attributes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this constraint:

```
[self.view addConstraints:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=topSpace)-[topLabel]"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:@{@"topSpace":@(self.view.bounds.size.height*0.66f)}
                                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topLabel)]];
```

I suggest you call this in `viewDidAppear:` or after because before then the height would be zero.

Comment: Height would be valid once you get to `-viewDidLoad`, no?  (Or `-awakeFromNib`, if on desktop)

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, that's annoying isn't it. Assuming your view controller is the full height of the screen, you can use NSLayoutAttributeBottom instead of height, which should give you the same result.

Comment: Awesome! Haven't thought of it!

Comment: This works great, thanks. Same for using .Right when computing the subview's .Leading.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't read right - the top of self.myLabel should be >= 0.66 * self.view.height?  The height of self.myLabel is one thing, the top of it is another.  If you can pin the bottom edge of self.myLabel to the bottom edge of the superview, then I think if you set a constraint like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myLabel
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                            toItem:self.view
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                        multiplier:0.66
                                          constant:0];
```

That should make sure that the height of self.myLabel is always at least 2/3rds the height of the root view.